# Swift MKLocalSearchRequest to get more than 10 results

Tags: swift, mklocalsearchrequest

I know how to search for local establishments but I'm curious if it's possible to display more than just 10 results from the search?

Here's my code to perform the search.

```
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Bars"
    request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((currentLocation?.coordinate)!, 400, 400)

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("Error occured in search \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else if(response!.mapItems.count == 0){
            print("No matches found")
        }
        else{
            for item in response!.mapItems{
```

Comment: Apple has made it clear: The server is a shared resource, with limits imposed. Accept them. If you try to overdo it you'll be throttled.

Comment: So there is no way to obtain more than 10 results?